# Ionic Create Project Error - Cannot find module

Tags: ionic-framework, installation

When I create ionic project with below command, I got a error

**Command** : `ionic start --v2 myApp tabs`

> **Error**: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\İbrahim Aker\AppData\Roaming\npm\ode_modules\ionic\bin\ionic'

I noticed that try to find path "ode_modules", but ionic path is "node_modules"

How can I solve this problem

thank you

Comment: Error is 
Cannot find module 'C:\Users\İbrahim Aker\AppData\Roaming\npm\ode_modules\ionic\bin\ionic'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3

Answer (score 0):

Your windows user name causing this problem because it has non-English character('İ'). You can solve this with creating new windows user.
For example :Ibrahim

'C:\Users\Ibrahim Aker\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic'